# Yeoman Installing Dependencies required version

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yarnpkg

I have a generator working with Yeoman, and one of the steps into the generation process installs fours Node Modules, Its ok, but I would like to define an specific version for those packages.

This is what I have in my generator:

```
installingDependencies() {
  this.yarnInstall(
    ['webpack','babel-core', 'babel-loader', 'babel-preset-es2015'],
    { 'dev' : true }
  );
}
```

These are the versions needed:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
  "webpack": "^2.2.1"
}
```

Any Idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the values are passed to the command line, so this will work:

```
this.yarnInstall([
  "browser-sync@^2.18.12"
], { dev: true });
```

Comment: @Javingka it would be great if you could accept this answer